# `name': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

To make a setter and a getter for `Dessert` class, I made the following code:

```
class Dessert 
  def initialize(name,calories)
    @name=name
    @calories=calories
  end
  def name
    @name
  end
  def name=(names)
    @name=names
  end
  def calories
    @calories
  end
  def calories=(calory)
    @calories=calory
  end       
end

d=Dessert.new("Salad",1200)
puts d.name("Khoresht")
puts d.calories(1600)
puts d.name()
puts d.calories()
```

The setter and getter must have the same name, and the compiler recognizes them by their signature. But here, I face the error:

```
`name': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

for the method name (the setter).

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change `d.name("Khoresht")` to `d.name=("Khoresht")`

```
d=Dessert.new("Salad",1200)

d.name = "Khoresht" # use setter method, equal to d.name=("Khoresht")
d.calories = 1600 

puts d.name
puts d.calories
```

The setter and getter have different name, in your codes, setter method name contains a `=`.

Answer (score 2):

pangpang already answered your question. I just want to mention that it is uncommon in Ruby to define getter and setter methods.

Instead a common way is to use [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) to declare getter and setter methods. The following example is equivalent to your code:

```
class Dessert 
  attr_accessor :name, :calories

  def initialize(name, calories)
    @name = name
    @calories = calories
  end
end
```

And other option might be to inherit from [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html). The following example has the same behaviour than your code:

```
 class Dessert < Struct.new(:name, :calories)
 end
```

Comment: The version with struct has a difference: The parameters in `Dessert.new` are optional, there is a default nil.

Comment: @knut: Yes, you are right. I forgot about that difference.